# onclick, change class and reset the others

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have the following script using CSS Sprites that toggles between active and inactive states.
This works great however I would like only the 'current' bullet to remain active. So when its clicked it resets the others to the inactive appearance. Thanks in advance for any help.

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bullet').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('bullet').toggleClass('active');
    });   
  });
</script>
```

---

```
<a class="bullet" href="#"></a>
```

---

CSS

```
a.bullet {
  display:block;
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
  float: right;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  text-indent:-9999px;
  background:url(../images/bullets.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

a.bullet:hover {
  display:block;
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
  float: right;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  text-indent:-9999px;
  background:url(../images/bullets.jpg) 0 -10px no-repeat;
}

a.bullet:active, a.active { 
  display:block;
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
  float: right;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  text-indent:-9999px;
  background:url(../images/bullets.jpg) 0 -20px no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quick way to achieve what you want...

```
$(".bullet").live("click", function() {
    $(".bullet").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for posting a reply! Still not working I'm afraid, maybe its because I have 30 bullets with the same class 'bullet' - so I think its resetting them all including the one its just activated!

Comment: The $.live() function has been deprecated for  $.on() - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Except for the fact that it uses `.live`, this is a good solution. @dave, it removes the `active` class from *all* bullets, and then adds it to the one that was just clicked.

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong then!, will keep fiddling with it - Really appreciate the help!

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, I've sorted it (see below):`$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.bullet').click(function(){
   $('.bullet').removeClass("active");
 $(this).addClass("active");
    });   
  });`